# Tweaking linux kernel

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new to linux programming & interested to tweak linux kernel(though I am not sure, what to tweak, I am planning to write drivers for particular device). To learn internal of kernel, I have started from historic kernel release (first release).

My problem is, how to test whatever changes I am doing for development, without disturbing my current os environment.(ubuntu 12, 64 bit). Is there any way like virtual box, sandbox?

Along with these, if anybody send some good approaches to learn these things, I would be really greatful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

If you're new to linux programming then you really don't want to be tweaking the kernel. You really want to be an advanced programmer capable of programming drivers and complex software first.

But yes there is, you can can create a virtual machine using openbox or vmware. If you're really keen on tweaking the kernel you probably want to first just try compiling and configuring the kernel and seeing if that works.

Also make sure you're well acquainted with how the kernel works and advanced OS designs in general.

Answer (score 1):

Search in google fr "Kernel configuration" you u will get many links how to configure your own kernel.
And one more thing do not use a outdated version of kernel ,always use latest stable release , because a lot of code and API is changed in new versions and no book in market is updated so ,, u have to read from kernel documentation. Thats the best way to learn the most updated information about linux kernel

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can test your changes on any of the commonly available virtual machines (VMs); that way, whatever changes you make to the VM kernel won't affect native OS.

Personally, I prefer using [CentOS 64 bit](http://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/) on [VMWare Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0). With this setup, I got away with minimal system maintenance while was able to focus on the actual job at hand. Once the VM is up & running, you can download and compile one of the latest stable releases from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/). Instructions on compiling your downloaded version of kernel could be found [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html); however, this may require little tweaking based on your actual setup. Once the VM is running on your desired version of kernel, using a combination of cscope and ctags will help you immensely in kernel code browsing.

Finally, if you want to become a serious kernel programmer and write your own device drivers, you need to get familiar with it in the first place. Below are a few excellent references -

- [Linux Device Driver by Corbet, Rubini, Kroah-Hartman, 3rd edition](http://makelinux.net/ldd3/)
- [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love, 3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468)
- [Understanding the Linux Kernel by Bovet, Cesati](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005652)
- Linux kernel source (ideally placed into your /usr/src/$(DESIRED_KERNEL) path, symlinked to /usr/src/linux)

Going through these books is a tedious job and chances are that you may hit the roadblock from time to time. [kernelnewbies mailing list](http://kernelnewbies.org/ML) and StackOverflow are some of the few reliable places where people would be happy to answer to your queries.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer is really helpful. Thank you.